# jsoup selector to get direct content not children's

Tags: jsoup

How to get the value 499.00 using jsoup selector?

```
<label class="price-box">
    <span class="old-price price-cut">
       <i class="icon-rupee"></i>999.00
    </span>
    <i class="icon-rupee"></i> 499.00
</label>
```

The following selector is not giving any result.
http://try.jsoup.org/

```
.price-box :not(span.old-price, i)
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was 'away' from computer these days. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, there is no pure css selector that would select the text of an element, since that text is itself not an element. But since you are using JSoup, why don't you try this:

```
String html = "<body><label class=\"price-box\"><span class=\"old-price price-cut\">"
            + "<i class=\"icon-rupee\"></i>999.00</span><i class=\"icon-rupee\"></i>"
            + " 499.00</label></body></html>";
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements labels = doc.select("label.price-box");

for (Element label: labels){
    System.out.println(label.ownText());        
}
```

The Element.ownText() method is what you are looking for I guess.